# Sitecore Azure Packaging Error

Tags: c#, .net, azure, sitecore, sitecore-azure

I am trying to publish a vanilla Sitecore site to my local Azure emulator however I receive the following error:

> 6/6/2014 12:05:39DevFabricLCd01Role01PScBafProduction [P] Execute
>   package failed System.ApplicationException: 
>   DevFabricLCd01Role01PScBafProduction [P] Execute package failed ---> 
>   System.ApplicationException: Execute package is failed ---> 
>   System.InvalidOperationException: Build Package failed: Searching for
>   imported module Diagnostics at C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows
>   Azure.NET SDK\v2.0\bin\plugins\Diagnostics\Diagnostics.csplugin...
>   Searching for imported module Caching at C:\Program Files\Microsoft
>   SDKs\Windows Azure.NET
>   SDK\v2.0\bin\plugins\Caching\Caching.csplugin... Copying
>   'C:\Sitecore\Azure\Data\AzurePackages(3) DevFabric\SitecoreWebSite'
>   to C:\Sitecore\Azure\Data\AzurePackages(3)
>   DevFabric\DevFabricLCd01Role01ScBaf20140606110529.cspkg\roles\SitecoreWebRole\approot...
>   UCPack_Command_Line: Error : The specified path, file name, or both
>   are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260
>   characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.
>   at Sitecore.Diagnostics.Assert.IsFalse(Boolean condition, String
>   message) at
>   Sitecore.Azure.Managers.Pipelines.CreateAzurePackage.Azure.ExecutePackage.Action(RolePipelineArgsBase
>   arguments) at
>   Sitecore.Azure.Managers.Pipelines.BasePipeline.RolePipelineProcessor.Process(RolePipelineArgsBase
>   args) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- --- End of inner
>   exception stack trace ---

Has anyone seen this error before or know what causes it?

Comment: Not seen it before, but the cause is in your stack trace; "C:\Sitecore\Azure\Data\AzurePackages(3) DevFabric\DevFabricLCd01Role01ScBaf20140606110529.cspkg\roles\SitecoreWebRole\approot..."   Can you adjust your root directory to something like "C:\S\A" instead of "C:\Sitecore\Azure"?  should help things along.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root cause is from this line in the stack trace: *"Error : The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters."*

The Sitecore Azure module creates deployment packages in `$(dataFolder)\AzurePackages` by default. Unfortunately, if your data folder is already nested even mildly deep, you'll hit the folder/file name limit pretty quickly.

To remedy this, you can specify a different root folder for your Azure module deployment packages. In the Sitecore content editor, navigate to `/sitecore/system/modules/azure/[Your-Environment-Name]`. In the environment item there is a field named **Build Folder**. Use an absolute path to specify where Azure deployment packages should be created, e.g. `c:\AzurePacks` or something even shorter.